# Determine the curve that will maximizes the line integral $\int_\gamma \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

**Let** $\mathbf{F} = (x^2 - z, xy - x, xz + x)$ **be a vector field, and let $S$ be the unit sphere in** $\mathbb{R}^3$.

**Determine the simple, closed curve** $\gamma$ **(orientation does not need to be determined) lying on the surface $S$ that maximizes the line integral** $$\int_\gamma \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r}$$

**Answer:**

Since the curve is simple, it must enclose an area $Z$ on the unit sphere, and Stokes' theorem states that

$$\int_\gamma \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r} = \iint_Z \text{rot} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{n} \, dS = \iint_Z [0, -2 - z, -1 + y] \cdot [x, y, z] \, dS = \iint_Z (-2y - z) \, dS$$

This integral is maximized when $(x, y, z)$ traverses all points where $-2y - z > 0$. The boundary $\gamma$ is therefore given by the intersection of the sphere with the plane $-2y - z = 0$. Substituting $z = -2y$ into the sphere equation, we obtain $$1 = x^2 + y^2 + (-2y)^2 = x^2 + 5y^2$$ Thus, the curve $\gamma$ is a great circle parametrized by $$\mathbf{r}(t) = [\cos t, \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \sin t, -\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} \sin t]$$

So I don't understand the part where they are saying $-2y - z > 0$ and then they go and make $-2y - z = 0 $ why is that?

Comment: The inequality $−2y−z>0 $ is related to $Z$, the equality $−2y−z=0$ is related to the boundary of $Z$, i.e. $\gamma$

Comment: I can't see the difference. I don't get it.

Comment: What if you were trying to maximize the line integral $\int_{C}(-2x-y)\mathrm{d}s$ where $C$ is a subset of the unit circle. Do you know what $C$ would maximize the line integral?

Comment: I guess when C is equal to the unit circle.

Comment: No. You only $C$ to capture the potion of the unit circle on which $-2x-y$ is positive.

Comment: Okay this entire sentence "This integral is maximized when (x,y,z) traverses all points where −2y−z>0" doesn't make sense for rn.

Comment: Still need help with this one if anyone is still up? Why does -2y-z = 0 give me an intersection between the sphere and the plane?